# Python Pass by Reference and dictionary copies

Tags: python, dictionary, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a script in Python to simulate a tournament of debaters. But I'm running into this weird error which looks like a pass by reference issue, but has some behavior that shouldn't be affected by pass by reference.

Basically teams is a dictionary of teams, where each team has a bunch of fields including a wins and losses field that both are initialized as 0 when I first build the teams.

Then df.apda_tournament() takes in a teams dictionary, and alters it to give the teams wins and losses based on the simulation, and returns the updated teams dictionary.

Due to how pass by reference works, the teams dictionary passed into df.apda_tournament() and the one returned end up both being altered, as the function alters the wins and losses of the records in the passed dictionary and returns it. Thus:

```
apda_results == apda_teams
```

Returns True as I would expect.

The odd thing is that df.apda_tournament() also alters the original teams dictionary which apda_teams is a copy of. So it ends up being that:

```
apda_teams == teams
```

Also returns true. Which is odd, as it seems apda_teams when I declare it is just a reference to teams instead of a copy, which I wouldn't expect since I declared it outside of a function.

Can someone explain exactly what is going on here? Also how can I avoid this such that apda_teams is actually a unique copy of the teams dictionary and not just also a reference to the records in memory?

Attached below is the code:

```
import debate_functions as df

dbtr_num = 64
team_num = dbtr_num / 2
dbtr_mn_mn = 200
dbtr_mn_std = 80
dbtr_std_mn = 80
dbtr_std_std = 60
judge_bias = 70

dbtrs = df.make_debaters(dbtr_num, dbtr_mn_mn, dbtr_mn_std, dbtr_std_mn, dbtr_std_std)
teams = df.make_teams(dbtrs, dbtr_mn_mn, dbtr_mn_std)
print(teams)
apda_teams = teams
para_teams = teams

apda_results = df.apda_tournament(5, apda_teams, judge_bias)
print('Check this')
print(apda_results == apda_teams)
print(apda_teams == teams)
```

Running it returns:

```
Check this
True
True
```

Comment: Python does not work like C with its pass by reference or value concepts. To cut the long story short:if you don't explicitly copy a dictionary it will stay the same object on calls and assignments.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I was wondering specifically about teams in this code, as I do explicitly copy it to apda_teams, and then only call functions on apda_teams, yet teams is being modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python list, dictionary are mutable(we can modify content). So whenever you pass list, dictionary to any function or assign to any variable then it is point to reference of given variable.

string, number, tuple are immutable (we cannot modify content). So whenever you string tuple, number to any function or assign to any variable then it just copy the value.

Comment: yeah, I understood that, and that's why (apda_results == apda_teams) evaluates to True. What I was wondering about is why (apda_teams == teams) also evaluates to true, when apda_teams is a copy of teams that then gets altered when it is passed to a function. Right now teams is also being altered by apda_teams being passed to the function, even though teams is never passed through any function.

Comment: sorry for delay, apda_teams = teams (assignment same as reference), you need to perform deepcopy like apda_teams = dict(teams) or for list apda_teams = list(teams)